# Bootstrap accordion collapse - one tab working, one not

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Twitter bootstrap accordion layout with two adjacent panes. Events in DayOne animate fine, in DayTwo not. The javascript console registers the collapsing action in both panes, but DayTwo events don't slide.

I suspect it's something simple but I'm at a loss. Thank you for any assistance!

```
    <section class="nav-tabs-default hidden-xs">
      <!-- Parent Nav Tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#DayOne" data-toggle="tab">
          <div class="title">Day 1</div>
          <div class="subtitle">06/10/2015</div>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#DayTwo" data-toggle="tab">
          <div class="title">Day 2</div>
          <div class="subtitle">06/11/2015</div>
        </a></li>

      </ul>

      <!-- Parent Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="DayOne">

            <!-- Child 1 Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="DayOne-1">
                <div class="panel-group timeline-schedule" id="panelTimelineOne">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="speaker-wrapper">
                      <img src="assets/img/speaker/speaker-1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="speaker-1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <div class="panel-title">
                        <div class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2:00 PM</div>
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panelTimelineOne" href="#itemOne">
                          Title event 1
                          <div class="pull-right fa fa-angle-up"></div>
                          <div class="pull-right fa fa-angle-down"></div>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="itemOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <article>
                          <p>Info event 1</p>
                        </article>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="speaker-wrapper">
                      <img src="assets/img/speaker/speaker-2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="speaker-2" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <div class="panel-title">
                        <div class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5:40 PM</div>
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panelTimelineOne" href="#itemTwo" class="collapsed">
                          Title event 2
                          <div class="pull-right fa fa-angle-up"></div>
                          <div class="pull-right fa fa-angle-down"></div>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="itemTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <article>
                          <p>Info event 2</p>
                        </article>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>



        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="DayTwo">
            <!-- Child 2 Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="DayTwo-1">
                <div class="panel-group timeline-schedule" id="panelTimelineOne">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="speaker-wrapper">
                      <img src="assets/img/speaker/speaker-1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="speaker-1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <div class="panel-title">
                        <div class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 11:00 AM</div>
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panelTimelineOne" href="#itemOne">
                          Title event 3
                          <div class="pull-right fa fa-angle-up"></div>
                          <div class="pull-right fa fa-angle-down"></div>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="itemOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <article>
                          <p>Info event 3</p>
                        </article>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="speaker-wrapper">
                      <img src="assets/img/speaker/speaker-2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="speaker-2" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <div class="panel-title">
                        <div class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3:00 PM</div>
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panelTimelineOne" href="#itemTwo" class="collapsed">
                          Title event 4
                          <div class="pull-right fa fa-angle-up"></div>
                          <div class="pull-right fa fa-angle-down"></div>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="itemTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <article>
                          <p>Info event 4</p>
                        </article>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: <div class="tab-pane fade" id="DayTwo">

Shouldn't this be : 

      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="DayTwo">

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have the same ID's and data-parents the collapsible items in tab 2 as you do in tab one. These must be unique. for example-- `href="#itemOne"` is on the toggle for the first item in both tab one and two.

See [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MJ0OSAiYyj) with your code fixed